# yii2 Updating Tables without primary key

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table named `SYSTEM_PARAMS` like below

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| name       | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| value      | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| created_by | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| updated_by | int(11) unsigned | YES  |     | 0                   |                             |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

where i have all names of the cron jobs i have to run and update the value against the specific job name with the current running `JobId`, the table does not have the `primaryKey` defined as you can see the schema above, so i defined the method `primaryKey()` inside the model like below

```
 public function primaryKey($asArray=FALSE) {
        return 'name';
    }
```

but this gives me error saying that i can define a static method as non-static , what am i doing wrong here.

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot make static method
>   yii\db\ActiveRecord::primaryKey() non static in class
>   common\models\SystemParams

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exactly what it says.

`primaryKey` is static method in ActiveRecord class.

If you want to override it you have to make it static as well.

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return ['name'];
}
```

PS. It must return array. See [this note](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php#L348).

Comment: hmm... but after defining it as static when i try to update the `value` field, it gives me another error 

PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

in F:\xampp\htdocs\Nxb\sms\_protected\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php:1098

Comment: i thought that might be because of the name of the column `value` so i renamed it to `job_id` , and still it gives me the  same error on `$model->save()`

Comment: Method must return array - is it in your case?

Comment: you are right i had to return as an array ,, thanks for your help @Bizley